# Using Variable in Remove-Item returns "A drive with the name '"E' does not exist"

Tags: powershell

I have been writing a script which searches for specific folders within an "Archive" folder and then zips them. Once the folder is successfully zipped I would like it to be deleted.

However, I am running into an issue where the `Remove-Item` cmdlet is returning the error "A drive with the name '"E' does not exist" when I use the `foreach` command and a variable.

If I run the `Remove-Item` command manually with the variable the issue does not occur.

Please let me know why this is happening and what I can do to stop it from happening.

Here is the code:

```
# Get list of archive folders
$ArchiveFolders = Get-ChildItem \*\*\* |
                  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |
                  Where-Object{ $_.Name -eq "_Archived"} | select FullName

# For each archive folder check which subfolders exist within it
foreach ($folder in $ArchiveFolders) {
  (Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select FullName | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Add-Content -Path e:\scripts\subfolders.csv
}

# Get list of Subfolders
$ArchiveSubFolders = Get-Content e:\scripts\subfolders.csv

# Select each Subfolder
foreach ($subfolder in $ArchiveSubFolders){
  # Move each subfolder to a 7z Archive with the highest compression rate available
  $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
  $pinfo.FileName = "7z.exe"
  $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
  $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
  $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
  $pinfo.Arguments = "a -mx=9 -t7z $subfolder.7z $subfolder"
  $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
  $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
  $p.Start() | Out-Null
  $p.WaitForExit()

  # Check Archive was created successfully and then delete the subfolder
  if ($p.ExitCode -eq "0") {
    Remove-Item -Path $subfolder -Force -Recurse
  } else {
    Write-Host "$subfolder has not been deleted"
  }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected, I just had to change the 7z.exe path to literalpath and
`Remove-Item -Path $subfolder -Force -Confirm:$false -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: @HiteshDhruna Please pay attention to the `ConvertTo-Csv` part in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell CSV export/conversion adds double quotes around the fields. Since you read that CSV output via `Get-Content` the double quotes are preserved on import, so you get paths `"E:\foo"` instead of `E:\foo`. This might work for constructing the external command, but it does not work for PowerShell cmdlets, because there is no drive `"E:` (with a leading double quote). It's usually a bad idea to make quotes part of the value. You're better off leaving the values without qoutes and adding quotes where they're required.

```
$ArchiveSubFolders = foreach ($folder in $ArchiveFolders) {
  Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName |
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Select-Object -Expand FullName
}
```

With that said, you don't even need most of your code. You can get the subfolders you want by changing your original path expression to `\*\*\*\_Archived\*` and run a single `Get-ChildItem` with that. I'd also recommend dropping the `System.Diagnostics.Process` approach and use the call operator (`&`) instead.

```
Get-ChildItem '\*\*\*\_Archived\*' | Where-Object {
  $_.PSIsContainer
} | Select-Object -Expand FullName | ForEach-Object {
  & 7z.exe a -mx=9 -t7z "$_.7z" "$_"
  if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    Remove-Item -Path $_ -Force -Recurse
  } else {
    Write-Host "$subfolder has not been deleted"
  }
}
```

Comment: The next part is to move this file to another folder which is stored on cheaper storage. I've tried the below but I'm getting an error "the path is not supported." Can you assist further?

`if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    $folder = (get-item $_).parent.parent.Name
    if (Test-Path "e:\archived\$folder") {
      move-item -path "$_.7z" -Destination "e:\archived\$folder\$_.7z"
  } else {
      new-item "e:\archived\$folder" -type directory
      move-item -path "$_.7z" -Destination "e:\archived\$folder\$_.7z" }
      Remove-Item -Path $_ -Force -Recurse
  } else {}
} `

Comment: @AndrewBeaumont Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.

Comment: apologies will do that now